# codium + pcmanfm-qt == 70+ CWD and SIZE commands per second

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, pcmanfm, vscodium

Local: Kubuntu 21.10, VSCodium 1.65.2, PCManFM-qt 0.17.0

Server: Windows Server 2016, FileZilla FTP Server

I use VSCodium (the MS telemetry free version of Visual Studio Code) as my editor, PCManFM-qt as my FTP client. It's a great combination because PCManFM doesn't prompt me to upload and overwrite remote files. Watching my FTP server in real time, the logs are as expected when I open PCManFM. It's fine when I open VSCodium with no open files. However, if I open a file from my server using PCManFM in VSCodium, one of those two programs starts bombarding my server with CWD and SIZE requests:

```
(000006)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> CWD /inet-folder/webcontent/Admin/printMapping/node_modules
(000006)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> 550 CWD failed. "/inet-folder/webcontent/Admin/printMapping/node_modules": directory not found.
(000004)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> CWD /inet-folder/webcontent/Admin/tsconfig.json
(000004)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> 550 CWD failed. "/inet-folder/webcontent/Admin/tsconfig.json": directory not found.
(000006)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> SIZE /inet-folder/webcontent/Admin/printMapping/node_modules
(000006)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> 550 File not found
(000004)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> SIZE /inet-folder/webcontent/Admin/tsconfig.json
(000004)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> 550 File not found
(000005)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> CWD /inet-folder/webcontent/Admin/jsconfig.json
(000007)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> CWD /inet-folder/webcontent/Admin/printMapping/bower_components
(000005)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> 550 CWD failed. "/inet-folder/webcontent/Admin/jsconfig.json": directory not found.
(000007)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> 550 CWD failed. "/inet-folder/webcontent/Admin/printMapping/bower_components": directory not found.
(000005)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> SIZE /inet-folder/webcontent/Admin/jsconfig.json
(000007)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> SIZE /inet-folder/webcontent/Admin/printMapping/bower_components
(000005)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> 550 File not found
(000007)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> 550 File not found
(000008)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> CWD /inet-folder/webcontent/tsconfig.json
(000008)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> 550 CWD failed. "/inet-folder/webcontent/tsconfig.json": directory not found.
(000008)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> SIZE /inet-folder/webcontent/tsconfig.json
(000008)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> 550 File not found
(000006)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> CWD /inet-folder/webcontent/jsconfig.json
(000006)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> 550 CWD failed. "/inet-folder/webcontent/jsconfig.json": directory not found.
(000006)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> SIZE /inet-folder/webcontent/jsconfig.json
(000006)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> 550 File not found
(000004)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> CWD /inet-folder/tsconfig.json
(000004)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> 550 CWD failed. "/inet-folder/tsconfig.json": directory not found.
(000004)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> SIZE /inet-folder/tsconfig.json
(000004)4/14/2022 22:25:14 PM - ftpuser (11.222.333.444)> 550 File not found
```

What sticks out to me are "bower_components" and "node_modules." Up to seventy per second. That's okay for a while, but then it starts to interfere with saving files and I get codium and PCManFM both as processes I can't kill.

- I don't use github, subversion, bitbucket.
- node is installed, but I've never used it that I know of, and I can't figure out how to remove it, or even if I should.
- bower is not installed.
- I've disabled all VSCodium extensions.
- I've tried every combination of Dolphin, PCManFM, VSCodium, Kate, and Visual Studio Code.
- ADDITIONAL INFO: **this only happens with .js files**. Once a .js file is opened, the server starts getting hit. Closing the .js file doesn't stop the behavior. Only closing VSCode stops it - if I do it before it locks up.

This behavior doesn't happen with Dolphin. It doesn't happen with Kate or Visual Studio Code, with .html/.css/.asp/.json files. Only the combination of VSCodium and PCManFM-QT and javascript files. I don't even know how to begin tracking down this issue.

The end goal is to stop the server bombardment and retain the use of VSCodium and PCManFM-QT if possible. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: I renamed the node_modules folder in /usr/share/codium/resources/app/extensions to *somethingelse* and the problem went away. Codium still appears to be operating normally.

Comment: A further note: this solution works with the .deb install, NOT the snap install.