# Is there a way to 'watch' what Codium itself is doing?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodium

I've posted before about [VSCodium and it's insane search for a "node_modules" folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71879989/codium-pcmanfm-qt-70-cwd-and-size-commands-per-second/72549093) via FTP after opening a javascript file. Up to now, my solution has been to rename one of Codium's folders (in the previous post) - I don't know why it works, but it does. Problem is, that disables all of the javascript formatting and validation. Not ideal.

I decided to see if I could find the offending code - it IS open source, after all. I think I've found the spot in tsserver.js - but to be sure I need to watch what Codium is doing.

Is there a console for Codium that I can log to? Is there some other way to watch Codium's inner workings?

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
codium --verbose
```

in a terminal.